# Does iptables -L show rules in order of execution?

Tags: iptables

When I'm looking at the output of iptables -L

```
# iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:1194
DROP       all  --  anywhere             ip-x.x.x.nydsl.com
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state INVALID
```

I've always assumed that the rules execute in order top to bottom.  But reading the documentation I haven't been able to verify that.  Can anyone confirm?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yup, it does (

> If the packet does not match, the next rule in the chain is the examined

). BTW, `iptables-save` gives a way more readable output.

Comment: Thanks!  I didn't know about iptables-save ... that's super helpful.